# Parsing a string to a LocalDate

Tags: java

I have:

```
String date = "05051990";
```

I need to parse it to a `java.time.LocalDate` in a format "dd. MM yyy."

I cant seem to make it work, please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    String date="05051990";
    LocalDate localDate =  LocalDate.parse(date,  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy"));
    date = localDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd. MM yyyy"));
    System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String date = "05051990";
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, dateTimeFormatter);
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd. MM yyy.");
        System.out.print(localDate.format(dateTimeFormatter1));
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 05. 05 1990.
> ```

JavaDocs of [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the ouput to your answer to make it more complete. If you don't like it, then feel free to remove it. Btw: try to use better variable names and not `dateTimeFormatter` and `dateTimeFormatter1`. Your code will then be harder to read. Better names could be `sourcePattern` and `targetPattern`. Just a note :).

Comment: Thanks Tom, really appreciate your feedback! I'll to improve that for next time!

Comment: Thanks guys, I made it.

Comment: I tried the same thing you wrote and variations. The problem was symbol for year is not yyyy but uuuu.