# Grails - converting a String to Date and then back to String

Tags: string, date, parsing, grails

I've got this string `21-04-2016` for instance, that I'm trying to convert to a date. After that's done I need to flip it around, remove all the dashes and then convert it back to a string so that it looks like `20160421`. I have found some code that I'll post below but I want to know if there is a simple way of doing this, maybe without having to convert the string to a date? Anyhow, here's my (broken) code:

```
String from = region.startDate    //I get this string from a controller
Date fromDate = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', from) //.parse is depricated apparently
println(from)
println(fromDate)
```

Here's what I get back (from the println):

```
Wed Jul 08 00:04:00 SAST 16
11-04-2016
```

Comment: You mean to say you have '21-04-2016' this string and you want it to convert in '20160421' this form ?

Comment: `from.split('-').reverse().join()`

Comment: That seems to have worked. Thank you, my good man.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a string to a LocalDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31949663/parsing-a-string-to-a-localdate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to convert from String to Date in that case (you could use a `SimpleDateFormat` (or rather two) to do that, though); just use String and List operations from Java and Groovy:

```
from.split('-').reverse().join()
```